# How to apply :include in this scenarion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
modules=MenuModule.all(:order => "module_seq")
modules.each do |m|
  groups=m.menu_groups.all(:order => "group_seq")
  groups.each do |g|
    items=g.menu_items.all(:order => "item_seq")
    items.each do |i|
      puts i.name
    end
  end
end
```

UPDATE 
How to use include with order ?

```
Something like MenuModule.find(:all,:include => {:menu_groups(:order => "group_seq"), :menu_items(:order => "item_seq")},:order => "module_seq")
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1):

See: http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/nested-include-activerecord-option.html

```
 MenuModule.all(:include => [{:menu_groups, :menu_items}], :order => 'module_seq,modules.group_seq,modules.groups.item_seq')
```

If the item_seq is not what you want to sort on, you probably can sort using the ruby sort method. The mysql order clause in a nested join only will order by one constrain in the join, as far as I am aware.

Comment: But i want to fetch menu_groups and menu_items with the proper order by "group_seq" and "item_seq". How to use include with order by ?